# How to parse an array containing the trending topics from twitter json feed

Tags: objective-c, json, twitter

I have already in place the method to grab the trending topics from twitter for a specified location.
My question is, how do I parse this data from the JSON, so that I can then print the names and urls of the trending topics list.

This is what the twitter json feed response looks like:

```
(
        {
        "as_of" = "2013-08-05T18:16:52Z";
        "created_at" = "2013-08-05T18:06:52Z";
        locations =         (
                        {
                name = "San Francisco";
                woeid = 2487956;
            }
        );
        trends =         (
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#jaibrooksfollowingsession";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23jaibrooksfollowingsession";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23jaibrooksfollowingsession";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#megalodon";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23megalodon";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23megalodon";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#SharkWeek";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23SharkWeek";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SharkWeek";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#bartstrike";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23bartstrike";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23bartstrike";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "#mtvhottest";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%23mtvhottest";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23mtvhottest";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Justin Bieber";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Justin+Bieber%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Justin+Bieber%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "Nelson Cruz";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22Nelson+Cruz%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Nelson+Cruz%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = "The O.C.";
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = "%22The+O.C.%22";
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22The+O.C.%22";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = Biogenesis;
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = Biogenesis;
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=Biogenesis";
            },
                        {
                events = "<null>";
                name = PEDs;
                "promoted_content" = "<null>";
                query = PEDs;
                url = "http://twitter.com/search?q=PEDs";
            }
        );
    }
)
```

I save this response into an array called jsondata and then use this function to get for instance the first trend topic name and url, but it is not working.., the name value and url value is printing null.

```
- (void) decompose:(NSArray *)jsondata
{
    NSString *name = [[jsondata objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *url = [[jsondata objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog(@"name:%@",name);
    NSLog(@"url:%@",url);

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `jsondata` directly like that, you need to navigate in to the trends array:

```
NSArray *trends = [[jsondata objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"trends"];
```

Then you can loop over the trends and extract each name and URL.